# XmlDocument - SelectNodes

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, selectnodes

I have tried a fair few different ways without much look, I'm hoping someone will be able to help :-)

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListOrdersResponse xmlns="https://services.com/Orders/2013-09-01">
   <ListOrdersResult>
      <Orders>
         <Order>
            <Id>1</Id>
         </Order>
         <Order>
            <Id>2</Id>
         </Order>
      </Orders>
   </ListOrdersResult>
</ListOrdersResponse>
```

Tried:

```
var o =xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/ListOrdersResponse/ListOrdersResult/Orders/Order");
var o = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/ListOrdersResponse/ListOrdersResult/Orders");
var o = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//Orders");
var o = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//Order");
var o = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//Orders/Order");

var root = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("bk", "https://services.com/Orders/2013-09-01");
var orders = root.SelectNodes("descendant::bk:Orders/Order", nsmgr);

var root = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("bk", "https://services.com/Orders/2013-09-01");
var orders = root.SelectNodes("descendant::bk:Orders", nsmgr);
```

It just returns 0 records. :-(

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give more details on what you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("bk", "https://services.com/Orders/2013-09-01");
```

part is correct but then you need to use the prefix `bk` to qualify all element names in your XPath expressions e.g.

```
XmlNodeList orders = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//bk:Orders/bk:Order", nsmgr);
foreach (XmlElement order in orders) {
  Console.WriteLine(order.SelectSingleNode("bk:Id", nsmgr).InnerText);
}
```

Comment: Picked this over the answer above due to the none conversion of XmlDocument - XDocument

Answer (score 2):

How about using Linq2Xml? I find it easier to use.

```
XNamespace ns = "https://services.com/Orders/2013-09-01";
var orders = XDocument.Load(filename)
            .Descendants(ns + "Order")
            .Select(x => (int)x.Element(ns + "Id"))
            .ToList();
```

PS: Xml is case sensitive. Check your sample in question. `<Order>` and `</order>` etc.

Comment: So load my XMLDoument.InnerText into XDocument.Load?

Comment: @ClareBarrington No above sample is complete. It loads the xml from file and parse it. No need for XmlDocument. (BTW: Use `XDocument.Parse(xmlstring)`) if you want to load it from a string.

Comment: @ClareBarrington in general, prefer LINQ to XML (`XDocument`) to `XmlDocument` unless you have a compelling reason not to.  It's a much nicer API.  I'd also prefer the LINQ to XML query methods to XPath - again, unless you have a compelling reason not to.

Comment: I like this :            var results = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Orders").Select(x => new {
                id = x.Descendants().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "Id").Select(z => (int)z)
            }).SelectMany(x => x.id).ToList();